# Swap characters in string

Tags: string, python-2.7, swap

I am new to python and I want to know how can I swap two characters in a string. I know string is immutable so I need to find a way to create a new string with the characters swapped.
Specifically, a general method which takes a string and two indexes i,j and swaps the character on i with j.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As you correctly state, strings are immutable and can't be modified in-place - but we can create a new string with the swapped characters. Here's one idea: let's convert the string into a list, swap the elements in the list and then convert the list back into a string:

```
def swap(s, i, j):
    lst = list(s)
    lst[i], lst[j] = lst[j], lst[i]
    return ''.join(lst)
```

Another possible implementation would be to manipulate the string using slices and indexes:

```
def swap(s, i, j):
    return ''.join((s[:i], s[j], s[i+1:j], s[i], s[j+1:]))
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
swap('abcde', 1, 3)
=> 'adcbe'
```

Comment: Great, I was thinking of some way to do it through a list. Is it efficient in terms of time ? because I have to place it in a time critical program.

Comment: @Wajahat It's good enough. I prefer the first option as it creates less intermediate strings, but as usual it's better if we profile the code first before trying to optimise it prematurely.

Comment: Just a note to anyone looking to use this code, the second way its done with slices and indices does not work properly with negative indices in python3. I would recommend using the first method.