# Python - I am getting an error that says 'substring not found'

Tags: python, encryption

I am trying to make a transposition cipher encryption function for a class project.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

def swap(s: str, index0: int, index1: int):
    smaller = index0 if index0 < index1 else index1
    bigger = index0 if index0 >= index1 else index1
    if bigger >= len(s) or smaller < 0:
        return None
    ret = s[:smaller] + s[bigger] + s[smaller+1:]  # swap first
    ret = ret[:bigger] + s[smaller] + s[bigger+1:] # swap second
    return ret


def swap_encrypt(s: str, key:str):
    ret = s
    for key_chr in key:
        index = ascii_lowercase.index(key_chr)
        swap_this = index % len(ret)
        with_this = (swap_this + 1) % len(ret)
        ret = swap(ret, swap_this, with_this)

    return ret
s = ''
key = ''
def main2():
    s = input('Enter your message: ')
    s = cleanup(s)
    key = input('Enter your keyword: ')
    key = cleanup(key)
    ret= swap_encrypt((s), (key))
    print(cleanup(ret))

main2()
```

I am getting the error 'substring not found', is there something I am doing wrong?

If my input is =(‘SLOTH POWER’) for s,  (‘TOP’) for the key, my output should be: ‘RLOTPOHWES’

Is there also another to limit the functions to ord(), len(), and range()? If so, could I be shown how as well?

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\darks\OneDrive\Documents\7\ciphers.py", line 139, in <module>
    main2()
  File "c:\Users\darks\OneDrive\Documents\7\ciphers.py", line 136, in main2
    ret= swap_encrypt((s), (key))
  File "c:\Users\darks\OneDrive\Documents\7\ciphers.py", line 123, in swap_encrypt
    index = ascii_lowercase.index(key_chr)
ValueError: substring not found
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post and show the full text of the traceback. Please also correct your indentation, as your code is not runnable as is.

Comment: apologizes for the incorrect indentation.

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see what you have in `key_chr` If you have upper case char then you can't find it in `ascii_lowercase`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can't find the character in the `ascii_lowercase`, because your input is uppercase. Try "sloth power" instead of "SLOTH POWER", or use `s.lower()`.

Comment: or it needs `ascii_uppercase`

Comment: thank you. I have another question. Is there also another way to limit the functions to ord(), len(), and range() in making the transposition function? If so, could I be shown how?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to simplify your code and replace part of it with the built in functions?

Comment: yes, I tried doing so, but I got lost where I tried to define my alphabet and assign it to the indexes of the message and keyword.

Comment: To simplify the `swap` function use the code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/25954716/14079544

Comment: what about the `swap_encrypt` function?

Comment: In my opinion the function `swap_encrypt` is OK.

Comment: could I somehow make the `swap_encrypt` with the ascii commands?

Comment: without ascii commands*

Comment: You can replace the `ascii_uppercase.index(key)` with `ord(key) - ord('A')`

Comment: for the decryption process, I would just do the opposite of `ord(key) - ord('A)` right? Which is `ord(key) + ord(A)` ?

Comment: For the decryption process simply call the `swap_encrypt` with reversed key. If the key is "TOP", the reversed is "POT". So the function can be `swap_decrypt(s, key): return swap_encrypt(s, key[:,:,-1])`.